# How to implement Voice search to SearchView

Tags: android, searchview

I want to add voice search function to my application. I'm populating a SearchView in SherlockActivity. But I  can't find a solution to add voice search function to SearchView object.

Can you please give an advice, what do I need to do?

Code below :

```
    public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {
        private SlidingMenu slidingMenu;
        private SlidingMenu slidingMenuRight;
        private String mFilterArrays[];
        public long lastScrollTime=0; /** En son kaydırma ne zaman yapıldı*/
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }   

        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

                    //Create the search view
                    SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
                    searchView.setQueryHint("Search...");


                    menu.add("Search")
                        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_search_inverse)
                        .setActionView(searchView)
                        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
                        return true;
    }
}
```

Mainfest

```
<activity
    android:name="com.paea.bcp.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.paea.bcp.MainActivity" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />                
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check out the documentation [**here**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html)

Update: If your SearchActivity is the same one, you can override onNewIntent and handle the Search intent there. Also make your activity as singleTop, that way only one instance of the activity will stay on top.

Hope this helps and please do notify if you find a solution.

Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

In your `res/xml` folder, you should have a searchable file (usually called `searchable.xml`).

Within the `<searchable />` element in that file, you should add this attribute:

`android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"`

There are other voice-related attributes (currently `voicePromptText`, `voiceLanguageModel` and `voiceLanguage`) which are all [described here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/searchable-config.html).

Answer (score 1):

In case you have a SearchView and not a SearchActivity you can do these two steps to solve such problem:

1. Declare searchable settings in the manifest.xml inside activity's tags like this:

   `<meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable" android:resource="@xml/searchable" />`
2. Then associate searchable settings with the SearchView in your activity class (i.e. in onCreateOptionsMenu() methods) like this:

   `SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
   SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);
   searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));`

For more information [see docs](https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup).